# Proving $A \implies B$ where $B$ is an if-and-only-if statement

Tags: logic, terminology

I'm working on a question where I want to demonstrate that $A\implies B$. This is pretty easy. You assume that $A$ is true and then show that $B$ is also true. However, what happens if $B$ is an if-and-only-if relationship?

I am trying to show that $A \implies (C\iff D)$. So again, I assume $A$ is true and want to show that $C\iff D$ comes as a natural consequence of $A$ being true. If I know that $C \iff D$ is a valid statement, can I demonstrate either $A \implies C$ or $A \implies D$?

Comment: If you know that $C \Leftrightarrow D$, then you do not need to show anything, you are already done. Why? Because independent of $A$ the statement $C\Leftrightarrow D$ holds true.

Comment: In logical terms you can also write A implies B as (not A or B). In your case if the B is an if and only if relation that you know is true. That simply makes the disjunction true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I know that C⟺D is a valid statement, can I demonstrate either A⟹C or A⟹D?

No.

Suppose we can value $C$ and $D$ as false but $A$ as true, then: $\def\too{\leftrightarrow} C\too D$ will hold, but *neither* of $A\to C$ or $A\to D$ shall.

---

But... why did you want to show that when what was to be proven was $A\to(C\too D)$ ?

If $C\too D$ is valid (true in all interpretations of statements $C$ and $D$), then $A\to(C\too D)$ will hold for any interpretation of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

As you already pointed out, to prove the statement $A \implies B$, you assume $A$ to be true and then show that $B$ is true as well.

If you want to prove the statement $A \iff B$, you have to show two things, namely $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$. The reason for this is that $(A \iff B) \iff ((A \implies B) \land (B \implies A))$ is a tautology, i.e., a statement that is *always* true. You can verify this with a truth table, where $T$ stands for 'true' and $F$ for 'false':

\begin{array}{cc|cc}
A & B & (A \implies B & \land & B \implies A) & \iff & A \iff B \\
\hline
T   & T   & T               & T       & T               & \mathbf{T}      & T          \\
T   & F   & F               & F       & T               & \mathbf{T}      & F          \\
F   & T   & T               & F       & F               & \mathbf{T}      & F          \\
F   & F   & T               & T       & T               & \mathbf{T}      & T         
\end{array}

There are many more tautologies, e.g. $(A \iff B) \iff (\lnot A \iff \lnot B)$, so to prove $A \iff B$, you could also show that $\lnot A \iff \lnot B$ holds.

If you want to show $A \implies (C \iff D)$, you can just read it as $A \implies B$ where $B = (C \iff D)$. That means you assume $A$ to be true and then show that the statement $B$ is true. Now, $B = (C \iff D)$, so you have to show that $C \iff D$ is true, which you can do just as you would go about proving practically any other equivalence: you show $C \implies D$ as well as $D \implies C$. Note that for showing these last two implications you can of course use the fact that $A$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Using direct proof (there are alternatives):

1. Suppose $A$ is true.
2. Suppose $C$ is true. Prove $D$ is true. Therefore $C \implies D$
3. Suppose $D$ is true. Prove $C$ is true. Therefore $D\implies C$
4. Therefore $C \iff D$ (from 2 and 3)
5. Therefore $A\implies (C \iff D)$ (from 1 and 4)